# Problema al convertir una serie en datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

me he enfrentado con un problema que no se como resolver. Tengo un dataframe que lo levanto desde un PDF. En este hay una columna que me indica la fecha en el siguiente formato: 01/06/2011. Dejo una captura para que vean como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo convertir la columna 'Fecha' al siguiente formato: 'nov-2020'. He probado convirtiendo primero dicha columna a datetime mediante lo siguiente:

```
data1['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['Fecha'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Fecha' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)
```

Alguno me podría ayudar a convertir esta columna al formato '%m-%y'??

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El código necesario para transformar la columna no está mal encaminado.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"fecha":["15/11/2020", "22/11/2020"], "instrumento":["ZS4","ZS4"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['as_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['formated_date'] = df['as_date'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

Lo que puede estar sucediendo es que algún dato de la columna este en un formato distinto, y eso este causando que falle la conversión.

El formato para Nov-2020 es en realidad '%b-%Y'.

Comment: Gracias @fabran99! 
He encontrado que algunos valores de la columna tenían otro formato, por lo que tuve que solucionar de otra manera.

`data1['Fecha'] = data1['Fecha'].astype(str).str.replace(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '')`

` data1['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['Fecha'], format='%d%m%Y')`

`fecha = []
recorrido = data1['Fecha'].to_list()

for elemento in recorrido:
    a = datetime.datetime.strftime(elemento, '%b-%y')
    fecha.append(a)`
`data1['Fecha1'] = fecha`.